# Connections gone after Upgrade Aptana Plugin to 3.0.9

Tags: aptana, connection

I use Eclipse Indigio with Aptana Plugin.
After last Upgrade, all Connections inside of my Projects are gone.

I've found the List of connections in my Backup of this folder:

> /.metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.ide.core.io/connections.xxxx

In this file, i see all my Connection-Settings like this:

```
<connection id="b333046c-45d1-4abb-a9c6-9671b082effb" type="ftp">
<name>arthus-yachting.de</name>
<host>arthus-yachting.de</host>
<path>/subdomains/shop/httpdocs</path>
<login>findeiss</login>
<passive>true</passive>
<transferType>BINARY</transferType>
</connection>
```

So i think, the first ID is the reference to the stored password. But WHERE is it stored?
Which data have i to recover to get all my connections back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im Workspace from Eclipse go to following hiddenpath:

/////.metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.ide.core.io/

There is a file named like this:

> connections.2470

All the connection-Data are saved there. Restore this file from your Backup - maybe increase the number after the dot of the filename - and you will be back up!

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, but I've had the same problem. Passwords are stored here:
~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.equinox.security/secured_storage

(Where ~ might be C://Users/USERNAME/

Although i have as yet been unable to make any use of this...